# How to count as one day from 5 pm to the next day 2 am in R?

Tags: r

I'm currently checking the daily progress of surveys participants to see if people have completed daily surveys. People receive our survey every day at 5 pm, and the survey disappears at 2 am the next day. so for example if a person receives a survey on 12/1/2019 and submit it at 1 am on 12/2/2019, the submission date would be 12/1/2019. However, currently the survey program calculates people's submission date based on their submission time. I would like to change this date and time range using R programming.

I have four columns in my data; (ID, Day, Date, Time).

[image: I have four columns in my data; (ID, Day, Date, Time)]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Here is sample data as `csv`:

```
ID,Day,Date,Time
DNP005,1,12/13/2019,01:31:47
DNP005,2,12/14/2019,21:48:33
DNP005,3,12/15/2019,00:10:02
DNP005,4,12/16/2019,00:41:44
DNP005,5,12/17/2019,22:34:10
DNP005,6,12/18/2019,17:54:06
DNP005,7,12/19/2019,00:35:17
```

and the output from `dput`:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "DNP005", class = "factor"),                                                                                                                  
    Day = 1:7, Date = structure(1:7, .Label = c("12/13/2019",                                                                                                                                                       
    "12/14/2019", "12/15/2019", "12/16/2019", "12/17/2019", "12/18/2019",                                                                                                                                           
    "12/19/2019"), class = "factor"), Time = structure(c(4L,                                                                                                                                                        
    6L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("00:10:02", "00:35:17",                                                                                                                                                     
    "00:41:44", "01:31:47", "17:54:06", "21:48:33", "22:34:10"                                                                                                                                                      
    ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,                                                                                                                                                  
-7L))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please don't put images of your data because we can't easily translate them into code. Please put the result of `dput(data)`

Comment: If you're looking for the survey date, then I suggest preserving the time component is a mistake (as it could easily be mistaken as yet another previous day). Better to either (a) convert to a `Date` and drop the time component, or (2) set the time to be the survey time (5pm). My answer assumes the former but it should be easy to adapt it to the latter (with `as.POSIXct`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` and `lubridate`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Create test data
df <- data.frame(
    date_completed = c("12/1/2019 17:55:00", "12/2/2019 01:55:00")
    )


 df <- df %>%
    mutate(survey_issued = case_when(
                mdy_hms(date_completed) %>% hour() < 17 ~ (mdy_hms(date_completed) - days(1)) %>% as_date(),
                TRUE ~ mdy_hms(date_completed) %>% as_date()
            )
    )
```

Note that this will create a new date object, if you need to retain a character type, you can reconvert:

```
 df <- df %>%
    mutate(survey_issued = case_when(
                mdy_hms(date_completed) %>% hour() < 17 ~ format((mdy_hms(date_completed) - days(1)) %>% as_date(), '%m/%d/%Y'),
                TRUE ~ format(mdy_hms(date_completed) %>% as_date(), '%m/%d/%Y')
            )
    )
```

---

Edit: just noticed from the alt-text in your image that `Date` and `time` are separate columns, here are updated snippets:

Creating a new column with date type.

```
df <- df %>%
    mutate(survey_issued = case_when(
                hms(Time) %>% hour() < 17 ~ (mdy(Date) - days(1)),
                TRUE ~ mdy(Date) %>% as_date()
                )
          )
```

Creating a new column and converting date type to character.

```
df <- df %>%
    mutate(survey_issued = case_when(
                hms(Time) %>% hour() < 17 ~ (mdy(Date) - days(1)) %>% strftime('%m/%d/%Y') %>% as.character(),
                TRUE ~ Date %>% as.character()
                )
          )
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample data:

```r
submissions <- as.POSIXct("2019-12-21 00:01:00", tz="UTC") + 3600*(0:24)
submissions
#  [1] "2019-12-21 00:01:00 UTC" "2019-12-21 01:01:00 UTC" "2019-12-21 02:01:00 UTC"
#  [4] "2019-12-21 03:01:00 UTC" "2019-12-21 04:01:00 UTC" "2019-12-21 05:01:00 UTC"
#  [7] "2019-12-21 06:01:00 UTC" "2019-12-21 07:01:00 UTC" "2019-12-21 08:01:00 UTC"
# [10] "2019-12-21 09:01:00 UTC" "2019-12-21 10:01:00 UTC" "2019-12-21 11:01:00 UTC"
# [13] "2019-12-21 12:01:00 UTC" "2019-12-21 13:01:00 UTC" "2019-12-21 14:01:00 UTC"
# [16] "2019-12-21 15:01:00 UTC" "2019-12-21 16:01:00 UTC" "2019-12-21 17:01:00 UTC"
# [19] "2019-12-21 18:01:00 UTC" "2019-12-21 19:01:00 UTC" "2019-12-21 20:01:00 UTC"
# [22] "2019-12-21 21:01:00 UTC" "2019-12-21 22:01:00 UTC" "2019-12-21 23:01:00 UTC"
# [25] "2019-12-22 00:01:00 UTC"
```

Solution:

```r
data.frame(
  submission = submissions,
  submitted = as.Date(submissions),
  survey = as.Date(submissions) - (as.integer(format(submissions, format="%H")) < 2)
)
#             submission  submitted     survey
# 1  2019-12-21 00:01:00 2019-12-21 2019-12-20
# 2  2019-12-21 01:01:00 2019-12-21 2019-12-20
# 3  2019-12-21 02:01:00 2019-12-21 2019-12-21
# 4  2019-12-21 03:01:00 2019-12-21 2019-12-21
# 5  2019-12-21 04:01:00 2019-12-21 2019-12-21
# 6  2019-12-21 05:01:00 2019-12-21 2019-12-21
# 7  2019-12-21 06:01:00 2019-12-21 2019-12-21
# 8  2019-12-21 07:01:00 2019-12-21 2019-12-21
# 9  2019-12-21 08:01:00 2019-12-21 2019-12-21
# 10 2019-12-21 09:01:00 2019-12-21 2019-12-21
# 11 2019-12-21 10:01:00 2019-12-21 2019-12-21
# 12 2019-12-21 11:01:00 2019-12-21 2019-12-21
# 13 2019-12-21 12:01:00 2019-12-21 2019-12-21
# 14 2019-12-21 13:01:00 2019-12-21 2019-12-21
# 15 2019-12-21 14:01:00 2019-12-21 2019-12-21
# 16 2019-12-21 15:01:00 2019-12-21 2019-12-21
# 17 2019-12-21 16:01:00 2019-12-21 2019-12-21
# 18 2019-12-21 17:01:00 2019-12-21 2019-12-21
# 19 2019-12-21 18:01:00 2019-12-21 2019-12-21
# 20 2019-12-21 19:01:00 2019-12-21 2019-12-21
# 21 2019-12-21 20:01:00 2019-12-21 2019-12-21
# 22 2019-12-21 21:01:00 2019-12-21 2019-12-21
# 23 2019-12-21 22:01:00 2019-12-21 2019-12-21
# 24 2019-12-21 23:01:00 2019-12-21 2019-12-21
# 25 2019-12-22 00:01:00 2019-12-22 2019-12-21
```

Shown as a frame solely to compare the wrong and right dates.

Comment: Thanks you so much!